# how to change navbar color when nav-toggle is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help changing my bootstrap navbar color when navbar-toggle is clicked. it just wont work.

```
$( ".navbar-toggle" ).click(function() {
$( ".navbar" ).css( "background","yellow" );
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/Lp2pjcm0/)

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
$("nav").toggleClass("navbar-yellow");
})
```

Create this class in css

```
.navbar-yellow{

    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Its navbar-default that is giving the gray color.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap 4, the class on the menu button is navbar-toggler instead of navbar-toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$( ".navbar" ).css( "background","yellow");
```

to this:

```
$( ".navbar" ).css( "background","yellow !important");
```

Bootstrap default navbar css is probably overwriting the one you are adding. Use `!important` to overwrite it.

Comment: strange..still nothing.

Comment: Won't work. "*When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property.*", [source](http://api.jquery.com/css/). Inline styles overrule all other styles in separate stylesheets (unless the `!important` rule is used in the stylesheet).

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom css class and add it when user interact with your UI.

```
//into your css file
.navbar.activated {
   background: yellow;
}


//into your js file
$( ".navbar-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( ".navbar" ).addClass( "activated" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap 3

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(event, c){
    $(event.target).addClass("disabled");
        $("nav").toggleClass("navbar-yellow");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $(event.target).removeClass("disabled");
    },500);
})
```

Or for bootstrap 4 and 5

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function(event, c){
    $(event.target).addClass("disabled");
        $("nav").toggleClass("navbar-yellow");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $(event.target).removeClass("disabled");
    },500);
})
```

CSS

```
.navbar-yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rdx7j5a9/34/