# Navbar dropdown always stays below other dropdown, increasing z-index etc doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have the following overlap problem with my dropdowns:
[image: Image of current problem]

As you can see if I press my most right button (the filter logo) and then press my dropdown link it overlaps in an ugly way. I would like that the "Dropdown link" dropdown always goes on top.

I have tried playing with the CSS (z-index, position, display, etc.) of both dropdowns, but I can't seem to figure it out. From what I understand z-index should solve my problem, but it doesn't. So that's why I went to play with position / display etc, but that didn't help either and confused me even more.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Would really appreciate a push in the right direction. (Other random feedback on my current code is also  appreciated)

My code:

https://jsfiddle.net/afbs97dy/4/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.test.com"><img class="logoklant" src="images/test.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand naamdashboard" href="#">test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto menuitems" id="myNavbar">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#page1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#page2">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#test1">Link 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="" id="filter">
                <i class="fas fa-filter filterlogo"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownqlik">
                <div id="CurrentSelections" class="qvobjects">
                  <div class="current-selections-placeholder">
                    <span>Connect to app to see Selection Toolbar</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</nav>



</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
/* navbar */
.navbar {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.logoklant {
    height:40px;
}

.naamdashboard {
    font: 20px;
}

.filterlogo {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.dropdownqlik {
    height: 36px;
}

#filter.is-active + .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100.1%;
  top:53px;
}

.is-pos-static {
  position: static !important;
  color: white !important;
}

#CurrentSelections {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left:-1px;
}

/* Scroll to top */
.scrollToTop {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 95vh;
    right: 1vw;
    z-index: 3000;
}

.scrollToTopLogo {
    color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243406/change-color-on-hover-and-when-navbar-toggle-is-collapsed */
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#filter").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('is-pos-static');
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});



});
```

Thanks for taking your time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add CSS

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Nice clean solution!

Comment: This worked, thanks, for people wondering what I did wrong. I was changing values in this class: .dropdown-menu. The problem with this, is that it edit's the z-index of both dropdown's, so the situation stays the same. With this solution you only edit the css of 1 of the dropdown's and even z-index: 1001 is enough.